# D3.js method for converting pie chart into spectrum display

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create a d3 template for a spectrum display, mostly geared for qualitative data. Imagine something like this:

[image]

I have got as far as a semi circle:

```js
var margins = {top:250, bottom:300, left:250, right:100};

var height = 600;
var width = 900;

var totalWidth = width+margins.left+margins.right;
var totalHeight = height+margins.top+margins.bottom;

var svg = d3.select('body')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', totalWidth)
    .attr('height', totalHeight);

var graphGroup = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', "translate("+margins.left+","+margins.top+")");

var pie = d3.pie()
            .value(function(d){return d})
            .sort(null);

var outerRadius = (400 / 2);
var innerRadius = 100;

var arc = d3.arc()
  .innerRadius(innerRadius)
  .outerRadius(outerRadius)
  .startAngle(0)
  .endAngle(Math.PI);

var arcLine = d3.arc()
  .innerRadius(innerRadius)
  .outerRadius(outerRadius);

/*
var pieG = graphGroup.selectAll(".arc")
    .data(pie(data))
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "arc");
*/

var path = graphGroup.append('path')
  .attr("d", arc)
  .attr("transform", 'rotate(-90)')
  .style('stroke','#000')
  .style('stroke-width',"2px")
  .style('fill', "none");
  
/*
var semicircle = pieG.append("path")
   .attr("fill","white")
   .attr("d", d3.arc()
     .endAngle(Math.PI)
     .startAngle(percentage * Math.PI)
     .outerRadius(radius - 10)
     .innerRadius(radius - 70));
*/
```

```html
   <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Then it dawned on me; if this template is to be re-usable I will have to calculate the "segments" from scratch. Suppose I had 6 categories like the above graph, then I'd have to iterate over every 30 degrees. And I'm not sure how that would work at all -- feeble attempt below:

```
var segmentLines = graphGroup.append('line')
    .attr('x1',???)
    .attr('x2',???)
    .attr('y1',???)
    .attr('y2',???);
```

Even IF I figured out the right xs and ys, that would only be 1 line -- and I need a total of 5 for a spectrum display of 6 categories. Heaven forbid I had 20 categories -- I can't find a way to make it scale.

### Question

Is there any dedicated method that d3 could bring to bear for a spectrum display? If not, is my pie chart approach the next best thing; and would it be scalabe? For illustrations sake, imagine we had a variable like:

`var categories = 6;`

Such that, depending on this number, the pie/donut chart would be cut up into that many pieces. (thus a template-esque graph).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is a pie generator...

```
var pie = d3.pie()
    .startAngle(-Math.PI/2)
    .endAngle(Math.PI/2);
```

... to which you pass a data array based on your `categories`:

```
var data = d3.range(categories).map(()=>1);
```

Here is a demo:

```js
var height = 300;
var width = 500;

var categories = 6;
var data = d3.range(categories).map(()=>1);

var svg = d3.select('body')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height);

var graphGroup = svg.append('g')
  .attr('transform', "translate(250,250)");

var pie = d3.pie()
 .startAngle(-Math.PI/2)
  .endAngle(Math.PI/2);

var outerRadius = (150);
var innerRadius = 100;

var arc = d3.arc()
  .innerRadius(innerRadius)
  .outerRadius(outerRadius);

var path = graphGroup.selectAll(null)
  .data(pie(data))
  .enter()
.append('path')
  .attr("d", arc)
  .style('stroke', '#000')
  .style('stroke-width', "2px")
  .style('fill', "none");
  
  var path2 = graphGroup.selectAll(null)
  .data(pie(data))
  .enter()
.append('path')
  .attr("d", function(d){
    return arc.innerRadius(150)
      .outerRadius(200)(d)
  })
  .style('stroke', '#000')
  .style('stroke-width', "2px")
  .style('fill', "none");
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```